# Are shortcode functions applied while rendering the content, or are they executed and stored with the post content?

Tags: shortcode, nextpage

I'm not sure if I've asked the question properly, apologies for that! What I'm trying to do is, output a `<!--nextpage-->` tag via a shortcode. But it doesn't work, I guess because shortcodes are applied when the content is rendered, whereas `<!--nextpage-->` is resolved into links beforehand. Does anyone know if this can be done? Can I apply the `<!--nextpage-->` tag through my shortcode when the post is rendered?

Comment: Ever implemented the below?

Comment: @JohannesPille Actually I'm doing it for a self project, hence I work on it only on weekends, as I got full time work on weekdays! I'll be implementing it tomorrow and will definitely get back here! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know in what exact order filters are applied to `the_content();` and whether that's early enough, but if it doesn't work for you, I believe it is safe to assume that you're right in thinking that the shortcode is applied to late.

From [`/wp-includes/shortcodes.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L285) (line 296, wp 3.2.1) it can be seen that shortcodes are naturally resolved like so:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11); // AFTER wpautop()
```

Executing [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) instead when the `the_posts` hook runs should make sure they are executed early enough. `the_posts` runs immediately after posts are retrieved from the database. The following should work:

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'rutwick_shortcode_exec');

function rutwick_shortcode_exec($posts) {
    $post_count = count($posts);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $post_count; ++$i) {
        do_shortcode($posts[$i]->post_content);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

It might be that lowering the priority will suffice:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 9);
```

Let it be noted, that I have not tested the above and I'm not guaranteeing nothing. Also, you might run into conflicts with [`wpautop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), because if the above is applied, shortcodes (all shortcodes!) are now resolved before it filters the content.

**EDIT:** It might be safer to run your own replacement function that early (the following will assume your shortcode is called [next]):

```
function do_rutwick_shortcode($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('{\[next\]}','<!--nextpage-->',$content);
    return $content;
}
```

and call that using either one of the two above methods (i.e. hooking it into `the_content` with a lower priority number or replacing `do_shortcode(...)` with `do_rutwick_shortcode(...)` in the above `for` loop). If you choose to do that, using `add_shortcode` becomes superfluous. Also, if you opt for hooking into `the_posts` the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) could be run directly in said function, two would not be needed, i.e.:

```
$posts[$i]->post_content =
    preg_replace('{\[next\]}','<!--nextpage-->',$posts[$i]->post_content);
```

would save you a function call.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation! I was thinking of using the `save_posts` action to replace my shortcodes in the content with the `<!--nextpage-->` tag. But I'll try this solution.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde I like your idea also. Only caveat of hooking into `save_posts` would be the permanence of the replacement - when editing posts later, the you wouldn't see the shortcode in the editor anymore, `<!--nextpage-->` would be in there for good.

Comment: You're right... I didn't think of that!

Comment: Awesome! Hooking into `the_posts` worked! Now I can return the `<!--nextpage-->` tag from my shortcode! I checked the database entry for the post with `<!--nextpage-->` tags added directly into the post content, the entry has the tags. It means the tags too are resolved at a later point, even after `the_posts`. Thanks a lot! :)